# Why is pop-up still shown if condition is false?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden field in my asp.net page which defines a value that I have to use for a pop-up to display or not display:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfNoShowPopup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

generates to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentMain$hfNoShowPopup" id="hfNoShowPopup" value="IN PROGRESS" />
```

In my JQuery I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Enable after completing the form to show the pop-up
    if ($("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "COMPLETED" || $("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "IN PROGRESS") {
        centerPopupChoice();
        loadPopupChoice();
        alert("IN PROGRESS");
    }
    else {
        alert("COMPLETED");
    }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is, if the value is either COMPLETED or IN PROGRESS do not show the popup and alert IN PROGRESS, otherwise display the popup and alert COMPLETED.

When I do visit the page, and although the value is IN PROGRESS, I am still being displayed the popup.

How do I resolve it?

When I had just this:

```
if ($("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "COMPLETED")
```

it worked fine.

Comment: not in progress and not completed are opposites so if one is true the other one is false and vice versa, => one statement is always true => always alerts "in progress"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this then,

```
if ($("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "COMPLETED" && $("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "IN PROGRESS") {
    centerPopupChoice();
    loadPopupChoice();
    alert("IN PROGRESS");
}
else {
    alert("COMPLETED");
}
```

`&&` sign would check for both the values to be true.

As stated in comments, `true || false == true`. So that is why you were always getting the first alert box.

Comment: The alert is for testing only... if it is `!=` then don't display the popup

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, editted the answer if you want to check that condition, you need to check for both. Since `true && true == true` and `true || false == true`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the || with && otherwise you always have true

```
//Enable after completing the form to show the pop-up
if ($("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "COMPLETED" && $("#hfNoShowPopup").val() != "IN PROGRESS") {
    centerPopupChoice();
    loadPopupChoice();
    alert("IN PROGRESS");
}
else {
    alert("COMPLETED");
}
```

you want your val to be different from "COMPLETED" AND "IN PROGRESS", if you leave the OR condition both value would allow you in.

Comment: Silly me... Didn't really take into the logic :/! Upvoted your answer and Accepted the other peron's since he replied first. Thanks though.